# Go Docker SDK: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, go

I want to connect to my Docker server running on my local machine (Apple M2). When I run `docker ps` it shoes all the containers running which means Docker server is running, and I could verify that by going Docker desktop. But when I try to connect it via Docker Go SDK, it can't connect.

```bash
❯ go run main.go
2023/05/20 17:34:15 Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
exit status 1
```

Here is output of the command `docker context ls`:

```bash
❯ docker context ls
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                  KUBERNETES ENDPOINT                ORCHESTRATOR
default             moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                      https://35.186.144.128 (default)   swarm
desktop-linux *     moby                                                          unix:///Users/xencodes/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour and stop using go run with file name arguments.

Comment: @Volker reason?

Comment: Because I'll hurt yourself, its a loaded footgun. Just stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by going to Docker Settings > Advanced and enable Docker sock.